# How to save data so that it could be used by multiple controller?

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC for my website. 
I have 4 views Aview, Bview, Cview, Dview and I have different controller for each view Acontroller, Bcontroller, Ccontroller, Dcontroller. 
The Aview is a form, that takes the user input for fields a,b and pass that a, b to Bcontrolller. Based on this input, my service is called in Bcontroller to  extract some data d. My Bcontroller passes this data, d to Bview. But this data d is also used by Ccontoller and Dcontroller. How can I save this data, so that It could be used by more than one controller.

Comment: Put some code, what you have tried.be specific for your problem.